# Data in my iOS app vanishes after a couple of days

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, database

I have an iPhone app that stores data locally in an array. I was testing the app on my actual iPhone and it works fine except that the data vanishes after a couple of days. I am curious to see if this has happened to anyone else and if a solution was found. Here is a sample of the code that stores the data:

```
var doctorsArray = [Doctors]()

func storeDoctorsArray() {
    doctorsArray.sort(by: {(a: Doctors, b: Doctors) -> Bool in
        return a.firstName < b.firstName
    })

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:     doctorsArray)
    defaults.set(data,forKey: "stored_doctors_data")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

And to get data:

```
func loadDoctorsArray() {
    if let storedArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "stored_doctors_data") as? Data {
        doctorsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: storedArray) as! [Doctors]
```

Again as mentioned, the app works fine and the data stores and displays as expected but vanishes after a couple of days.

Comment: Not *quite* enough to actually duplicate anything. (The code you've posted so far appears to be good.) But *how* and *when* are you calling `storeDoctorsArray`? Same for `loadDoctorsArray`, how and when? As mentioned, are you "reinstalling" the app (that includes Xcode doing it)?

Comment: Calling `synchronize` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the app it clears the contents of `UserDefaults`. Other than that, or resetting the simulator, `UserDefaults` should persist between runs.

How/when are you calling your `loadDoctorsArray()` function

Comment: Well, according to Apple support one shouldn't use "User Defaults" to store persistant data as it and so now I now using "DocumentDirectory" to store data. This seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!